# How do you host Wordpress on Heroku in a subdirectory?

Tags: php, wordpress, heroku, nginx

I'm trying to migrate my Wordpress blog from Amazon EC2 (my free t1.micro ran out 9 months ago and I'm tired of paying $20/mo) to Heroku. I'm used [this project](http://mchung.github.io/heroku-buildpack-wordpress/) and everything worked really well, except for one problem: the blog is hosted at the root directory on Heroku and I want it hosted on "/blog".

I'm looking for two options, neither of which I can figure out:

1. Preferred option: figure out how to literally move the entire Wordpress installation from / to /blog. The simple approach of moving everything in to a subdirectory didn't work as Heroku complained that there was not a "supported app" when I tried pushing it.
2. Backup option: keep the blog hosted at / but modify the [nginx config](https://github.com/mchung/wordpress-on-heroku/tree/master/config/vendor/nginx/conf) to respond to /blog as well. This is less preferred because it'll mean I'll need to maintain working links at the root of my domain indefinitely, which I'd prefer to avoid.

So are there any Heroku+PHP and/or Nginx wizards out there that can help me out?

Comment: If it's just Wordpress you're working with, might it be less hassle just to use a simple LAMP VPS?

Answer (score 1):

I used WP Clone and it worked for me, install a clean Wordpress in the sub install WP clone on both installs do the backup on your live site then copy the ULR it gives you paste it into WP clone on the sub then update your permalink.  This will copy everything over leaving the original where it is in case anything goes wrong, I have moves sites with it, even to a different domain I haven't came across any problems.

Hope this helps

[wp-clone-by-wp-academy](http://wordpress.org/plugins/wp-clone-by-wp-academy/)